# Query a many-to-many relationship with linq/Entity Framework. CodeFirst

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

How can I query a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework code first and linq? The problem is that EF create automatically the relation table. So, I don't have it in my context.

This is the relational model:

[image]

I need a list of Articles for a specific Category_Id, basically replicate something like that:

```
select a.Id, a.Title,a.ShortDescription                       
from Articles a
join CategoryArticles ca on ca.Article_Id=a.Id
where ca.Category_Id  = @parameter
```

However my dbcontext only have :

```
public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var cat_id=1; // Change this variable for your real cat_id

var query= from article in db.Articles
           where article.Categories.Any(c=>c.Category_ID==cat_id)
           select article;
```

This way you will get the articles that satisfies the condition you want.  This is the sql code that is generated by that query:

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM [dbo].[Articles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[ArticleCategories] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Article_Id]) AND ([Extent2].[Category_Id] = @p__linq__0))
```

### Update

Another option could be using `SelectMany` extension method (as @Khaled pointed out) starting your query from `Categories` instead of `Articles`:

```
var query= db.Categories.Where(c=>c.Category_ID==cat_id).SelectMany(c=>Articles);
```

That would generate an Inner join instead of the `EXIST` that is product of `Any` extension method.

Comment: This is incorrect, EF is not smart enough to use joins.  It will instead create an EXISTS statement.  Performance can be an issue here.

Comment: @Talon, now I tested that query and it's true that EF 6.x Linq provider is generating an `Exists` instead of a `join`. Thanks for the feedback. Agreed with you about the performance but if you omit the junction table as part of your model this is the only way to do it.

Comment: @octavioccl agreed, I have not found a way around it without that junction table.  I'm thinking that these implicit junction tables are bad news but it's going to require a lot of work to remove them with minimal reward.

Comment: For faster queries using INNER JOIN, refer to Khaled's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41244639/193634

Answer (score 18):

How about

```
db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == categoryId).SelectMany(c => c.Articles)?
```

This should work fine (produce the right joined sql statement.)

Comment: where is the 'a' from? Could you clarify what you mean please.

Comment: It should be `c => c.Articles` .  This will join each article list of categories selected from Where query.

Comment: Great, this is right solution. EF generated INNER JOIN instead WHERE EXISTS.
With EXISTS is very slow.

Answer (score 4):

Example linq method syntax

```
int category_ID = 1;

var query = db.Articles
    .Where(a => a.Categories
    .Any(c => c.Category_ID == category_ID))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this and figured I'd post the solution I found for anyone stumbling across this page. This produces an `INNER JOIN`.

```
var category_id = 24;

var query = (from article in Articles
             from category in article.Categories.Where(x => x.Category_ID == category_id)
             select article);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the whole table including all the relationships, maybe try something like this:

```
List<CategoryArticle> rec = context.Category.SelectMany(a => a.Articles.Select(c => new CategoryArticle { Category_Id = c.Id, Article_Id = a.Id })).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add and query the junction table:

```
  var articles = (from ca in _context.CategoryArticles
                  inner join a in _context.Articles on a.Id equals ca.Article_Id
                  inner join c in _context.Catgories on c.Id equals ca.Category_Id
                  where ca.Category_Id equals catId
                  select c).ToList();
```