# Linq code for joining many to many tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm new at linq and need for your advice.

I created three tables.

**STUDENT ---- STUDENT_COURSE ----- COURSES**

[image: Database Diagram]

I simply want to list which students are taking which courses.

If I'm using dbml to doing this, I get the result in somehow like below.

```
var takencourses = from sc in dbe.STUDENT_COURSEs
               join s in dbe.Students on sc.SID equals s.ID
               join c in dbe.COURSEs on sc.CID equals c.Id
               select new { s.NAME, s.SURNAME, c.COURSENAME};

dataGridView1.DataSource = takencourses;
```

But I'm not able to run this with **Entity Data Model**.

When I'm adding entity data model `STUDENT_COURSE` table is disappearing and its adding references on the tables like below.

[image: Entity Data Model diagram]

Because I didn't have the STUDENT_COURSE table I couldn't write the LINQ for joining Student and Courses tables to get the result.

I simply want to take **NAME, SURNAME, COURSENAME** from Entity Data Model.

1. So how can I do it with using Entity Data Model?
2. What should be the equivalent lambda code for this?
   For Example I tried something like this `dbe.Students.SelectMany(s => s.STUDENT_COURSEs).ToList()` but I didn't find the correct result.
3. If I'm going to working on 100.000 rows, what will be the best choice for performance issues?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Either `from s in dbe.Students from c in s.COURSES select ...` or `from c in dbe.Courses from s in c.Student select ...` It would be nice if you use better class/navigation property names.

Comment: It is worked. Thanks. What about the other questions?

Comment: You're asking too many questions for one post. I consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30466696/861716) a duplicate.